# How to combine Celery with asyncio?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, celery, python-asyncio

How can I create a wrapper that makes celery tasks look like `asyncio.Task`? Or is there a better way to integrate Celery with `asyncio`?

@asksol, the creator of Celery, [said this:](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=11870293):

> It's quite common to use Celery as a distributed layer on top of async I/O frameworks (top tip: routing CPU-bound tasks to a prefork worker means they will not block your event loop).

But I could not find any code examples specifically for `asyncio` framework.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'look like'. I think maybe you misinterpret Asksol's comment - you put celery infront of frameworks such as Rabbit or SQS that is the async manager. As such you could possibly make a broker / plugin for celery which uses asyncio, but the tasks wouldn't "look like" (i.e. have the interface of) asyncio? The point of celery is to abstract the asynchronus methodology used?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

**EDIT: 01/12/2021 previous answer (find it at the bottom) didn't age well therefore I added a combination of possible solutions that may satisfy those who still look on how to co-use asyncio and Celery**

Lets quickly break up the use cases first (more in-depth analysis here: [asyncio and coroutines vs task queues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34437867/asyncio-and-coroutines-vs-task-queues)):

- If the task is I/O bound then it tends to be better to use coroutines and asyncio.
- If the task is CPU bound then it tends to be better to use Celery or other similar task management systems.

So it makes sense in the context of Python's "Do one thing and do it well" to not try and mix asyncio and celery together.

BUT what happens in cases where we want to be able to run a method both asynchronously and as an async task? then we have some options to consider:

- The best example that I was able to find is the following: https://johnfraney.ca/posts/2018/12/20/writing-unit-tests-celery-tasks-async-functions/ (and I just found out that it is [@Franey's response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39815771/how-to-combine-celery-with-asyncio/54373183#54373183)):

  1. Define your async method.
  2. Use [`asgiref`](https://pypi.org/project/asgiref/)'s `sync.async_to_sync` module to wrap the async method and run it synchronously inside a celery task:

     ```
     # tasks.py
     import asyncio
     from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
     from celery import Celery

     app = Celery('async_test', broker='a_broker_url_goes_here')

     async def return_hello():
         await asyncio.sleep(1)
         return 'hello'


     @app.task(name="sync_task")
     def sync_task():
         async_to_sync(return_hello)()
     ```
- A use case that I came upon in a [FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/) application was the reverse of the previous example:

  1. An intense CPU bound process is hogging up the async endpoints.
  2. The solution is to refactor the async CPU bound process into a celery task and pass a task instance for execution from the Celery queue.
  3. A minimal example for visualization of that case:

     ```
     import asyncio
     import uvicorn

     from celery import Celery
     from fastapi import FastAPI

     app = FastAPI(title='Example')
     worker = Celery('worker', broker='a_broker_url_goes_here')

     @worker.task(name='cpu_boun')
     def cpu_bound_task():
         # Does stuff but let's simplify it
         print([n for n in range(1000)])

     @app.get('/calculate')
     async def calculate():
         cpu_bound_task.delay()

     if __name__ == "__main__":
         uvicorn.run('main:app', host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
     ```
- Another solution seems to be what [@juanra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39815771/how-to-combine-celery-with-asyncio/57286909#57286909) and [@danius](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39815771/how-to-combine-celery-with-asyncio/48998252#48998252) are proposing in their answers, but we have to keep in mind that performance tends to take a hit when we intermix sync and async executions, thus those answers need monitoring before we can decide to use them in a prod environment.

Finally, there are some ready-made solutions, that I cannot recommend (because I have not used them myself) but I will list them here:

- [Celery Pool AsyncIO](https://pypi.org/project/celery-pool-asyncio/) which seems to solve exactly what Celery 5.0 didn't, but keep in mind that it seems a bit experimental (version 0.2.0 today 01/12/2021)
- [aiotasks](https://github.com/cr0hn/aiotasks) claims to be "a Celery like task manager that distributes Asyncio coroutines" but seems a bit stale (latest commit around 2 years ago)

---

*Well that didn't age so well did it? Version 5.0 of Celery didn't implement asyncio compatibility thus we cannot know when and if this will ever be implemented... Leaving this here for response legacy reasons (as it was the answer at the time) and for comment continuation.*

That will be possible from Celery version 5.0 as stated on the official site:

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/4.0/whatsnew-4.0.html#preface

> 

1. The next major version of Celery will support Python 3.5 only, where we are planning to take advantage of the new asyncio library.
2. Dropping support for Python 2 will enable us to remove massive amounts of compatibility code, and going with Python 3.5 allows us to take advantage of typing, async/await, asyncio, and similar concepts there’s no alternative for in older versions.

*The above was quoted from the previous link.*

So the best thing to do is wait for **version 5.0** to be distributed!

In the meantime, happy coding :)

Comment: This didn't happen, and celery 5 is not compatible with asyncio.

Comment: @piro I haven't used celery 5 as of yet, I will investigate it further! Thanks for the update

Comment: @piro Well, I did my research and refactored this answer, hope you can find something useful in there!

Comment: I opened [a feature request](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/6603) and they answered "it is a part of a bigger design decision which we are planning for **celery 6.0**".

Comment: @BenoitBlanchon very interesting! We will wait and see I suppose :)

Comment: Until we get official support in Celery, I found that [polling the status of the AyncResult](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66318397/1164966) provides an excellent workaround.

Comment: @JohnMoutafis I tried your solution with `async_to_sync` and it works on the first beat. But then I get this error: ```got Future <Future pending cb=[Protocol._on_waiter_completed()]> attached to a different loop```. Do you have any suggestions, please? Thanks

Answer (score 35):

This simple way worked fine for me:

```py
import asyncio
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks')

async def async_function(param1, param2):
    # more async stuff...
    pass

@app.task(name='tasks.task_name', queue='queue_name')
def task_name(param1, param2):
    asyncio.run(async_function(param1, param2))
```

Comment: It will work in tests, but what's the price of running the reactor in runtime on request?

Comment: This works, but all tasks run similarly will be run synchronously: asyncio.run(async1()) and on the next line asyncio.run(async2()). async1 and async2 will be run synchronously.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a simple helper that you can use to make a Celery task awaitable:

```py
import asyncio
from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async

# Converts a Celery tasks to an async function
def task_to_async(task):
    async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        delay = 0.1
        async_result = await sync_to_async(task.delay)(*args, **kwargs)
        while not async_result.ready():
            await asyncio.sleep(delay)
            delay = min(delay * 1.5, 2)  # exponential backoff, max 2 seconds
        return async_result.get()
    return wrapper
```

Like [`sync_to_async`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/async/#asgiref.sync.sync_to_async), it can be used as a direct wrapper:

```py
@shared_task
def get_answer():
    sleep(10) # simulate long computation
    return 42    

result = await task_to_async(get_answer)()
```

...and as a decorator:

```py
@task_to_async
@shared_task
def get_answer():
    sleep(10) # simulate long computation
    return 42    

result = await get_answer()
```

Of course, this is not a perfect solution since it relies on [polling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_(computer_science)).
However, it should be a good workaround to call Celery tasks from Django async views until  [Celery officially provides a better solution](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/6603).

EDIT 2021/03/02: added the call to [`sync_to_async`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/async/#asgiref.sync.sync_to_async) to support [eager mode](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/v4.4.7/userguide/configuration.html#task-always-eager).

Comment: That's a solid workaround and we already use this (not as a decorator though) in the FastAPI application mentioned in my answer :)
Keep in mind that you need to pay attention to the error handling and have a plan on how you want any potential exceptions to be handled!

Comment: `task_to_async` calls [`AsyncResult.get()`](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/v4.4.7/reference/celery.result.html?highlight=asyncresult#celery.result.AsyncResult.get), which re-raise any exception raised by the tasks. Of course, if you want to customize this behavior, you can add parameters to `task_to_async` and forward them to `async_result.get()`.

Comment: whats the point of wrapping the task in the async helper? couldnt you just implement the loop with sleep, without it? Afaik task.delay is non blocking. Only something like task.get would block.

Comment: @BenoitBlanchon Is it necessary to poll? Why not simply do `async_result = await sync_to_async(task.delay)(*args, **kwargs)` followed by `res = await sync_to_async(async_result.get, thread_sensitive=False)()`? Passing `thread_sensitive=False` would ensure it does not block the main thread.

Answer (score 7):

You can wrap any blocking call into a Task using `run_in_executor` as described in [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.run_in_executor), I also added in the example a custom [timeout](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait_for):

```
def run_async_task(
    target,
    *args,
    timeout = 60,
    **keywords
) -> Future:
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    return asyncio.wait_for(
        loop.run_in_executor(
            executor,
            functools.partial(target, *args, **keywords)
        ),
        timeout=timeout,
        loop=loop
    )
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
async_result = loop.run_until_complete(
    run_async_task, your_task.delay, some_arg, some_karg="" 
)
result = loop.run_until_complete(
    run_async_task, async_result.result 
)
```

Answer (score 5):

The cleanest way I've found to do this is to wrap the `async` function in `asgiref.sync.async_to_sync` (from [`asgiref`](https://github.com/django/asgiref/)):

```
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
from celery.task import periodic_task


async def return_hello():
    await sleep(1)
    return 'hello'


@periodic_task(
    run_every=2,
    name='return_hello',
)
def task_return_hello():
    async_to_sync(return_hello)()
```

I pulled this example from a [blog post](https://johnfraney.ca/2018/12/20/writing-unit-tests-celery-tasks-async-functions/) I wrote.

Comment: Very nice, I found your article during my research on the issue and I included it in the edit of my answer (I am mentioning you of course now that I found it out)! Thank you for the knowledge boost :)

Comment: Thanks! It's always cool to see references to my articles pop up, even if it's within the same thread.

Answer (score 4):

A nice way to implement Celery with asyncio:

```
import asyncio
from celery import Celery

app = Celery()

async def async_function(param):
    print('do something')

@app.task()
def celery_task(param):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    return loop.run_until_complete(async_function(param))
```

Answer (score 4):

For anyone who stumbles on this looking for help specifically with async `sqlalchemy` (ie, using the `asyncio` extension) and Celery tasks, explicitly [disposing](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html) of the engine will fix the issue. This particular example worked with `asyncpg`.

Example:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import (
    AsyncSession,
    create_async_engine,
)
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync


engine = create_async_engine("some_uri", future=True)
async_session_factory = sessionmaker(engine, expire_on_commit=False, class_=AsyncSession)


@celery_app.task(name="task-name")
def sync_func() -> None:
    async_to_sync(some_func)()


async def some_func() -> None:
    async with get_db_session() as session:
        result = await some_db_query(session)
    # engine.dispose will be called on exit


@contextlib.asynccontextmanager
async def get_db_session() -> AsyncGenerator:
    try:
        db = async_session_factory()
        yield db
    finally:
        await db.close()
        await engine.dispose()
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved problem by combining Celery and asyncio in the [celery-pool-asyncio](https://pypi.org/project/celery-pool-asyncio/) library.

Comment: This actually seems a great solution, only issue that it does not support celery 5. Any timeline for this ?

Comment: Sadly, the project is no longer maintained.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my implementation of Celery handling async coroutines when necessary:

Wrap the Celery class to extend its functionnality:

```
from celery import Celery
from inspect import isawaitable
import asyncio


class AsyncCelery(Celery):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.patch_task()

        if 'app' in kwargs:
            self.init_app(kwargs['app'])

    def patch_task(self):
        TaskBase = self.Task

        class ContextTask(TaskBase):
            abstract = True

            async def _run(self, *args, **kwargs):
                result = TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
                if isawaitable(result):
                    await result

            def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
                asyncio.run(self._run(*args, **kwargs))

        self.Task = ContextTask

    def init_app(self, app):
        self.app = app

        conf = {}
        for key in app.config.keys():
            if key[0:7] == 'CELERY_':
                conf[key[7:].lower()] = app.config[key]

        if 'broker_transport_options' not in conf and conf.get('broker_url', '')[0:4] == 'sqs:':
            conf['broker_transport_options'] = {'region': 'eu-west-1'}

        self.config_from_object(conf)


celery = AsyncCelery()
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this implementation that wraps @app.task decorator to implement async delay() and apply_async() functions. It depends on Redis and extends the redis backend to use a pubsub to wait for results. It's used with Django.

```
import json
import asyncio
import redis.asyncio
from celery.backends.redis import RedisBackend
from django.conf import settings
from MYAPP.celery import app


APOOL = redis.asyncio.ConnectionPool(host=settings.REDIS_HOST,
                                     db=settings.REDIS_DB,
                                     port=settings.REDIS_PORT)

CELERY_TASK_PREFIX = b'celery-task-meta-'

class PubSubBackend(RedisBackend):
    def __init__(self, *argz, **kwargs):
        kwargs['host'] = settings.REDIS_HOST
        kwargs['port'] = settings.REDIS_PORT
        kwargs['db'] = settings.REDIS_DB
        super().__init__(*argz, **kwargs)

    # This backend client will publish to subscribers when a task is finished
    def set(self, key, value, **retry_policy):
        return self.client.publish(key, value)

class RemoteTaskException(Exception):
    pass


class RemoteTaskTimeout(Exception):
    pass


TIMEOUT = 10
async def _read_task_result(channel, future):
    import time
    limit = time.time() + TIMEOUT
    while time.time() < limit:
        message = await channel.get_message(ignore_subscribe_messages=True)
        if message is not None:
            future.set_result(message)
            return
    future.set_result({'data': json.dumps(
        { 'status': 'TIMEOUT' },
    ).encode()})

async def get_task_result(task_id):
    future = asyncio.Future()
    conn = redis.asyncio.Redis(connection_pool=APOOL)
    async with conn.pubsub() as pubsub:
        queue = f'{CELERY_TASK_PREFIX.decode()}{task_id}'.encode()
        await pubsub.subscribe(queue)
        return_task = _read_task_result(pubsub, future)
        await asyncio.create_task(return_task)
        result = future.result()
        result_data = json.loads(result['data'].decode())
        status = result_data['status']
        if status == 'SUCCESS':
            return result_data['result']
        elif status == 'FAILURE':
            raise RemoteTaskException(result_data['result']['exc_message'][0])
        elif status == 'TIMEOUT':
            raise RemoteTaskTimeout()
        else:
            raise Exception(f'Uknown task status {status}')


class AsyncTask:

    def __init__(self, sub):
        self.task = app.task(sub)

    async def delay(self, *args, **kwargs):
        task = self.task.delay(*args, **kwargs)
        return await get_task_result(task.id)

    def s(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.task.s(*args, **kwargs)

    async def apply_async(self, *args, **kwargs):
        task = self.task.apply_async(*args, **kwargs)
        return await get_task_result(task.id)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.task(*args, **kwargs)


# Task decorator
def async_task(sub):
    return AsyncTask(sub)
```

Then, in settings.py:

```
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'myapp.somewhere.PubSubBackend'
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Celery has clear producer-consumer separation. @john-moutafis has covered the consumer side very well.
2. I reckon that producer side also deserve some attention, where asyncio and celery paradigms can be naturally mixed.
3. Since tornado is a well known asyncio server framework, I searched tornado and celery, and found a nice example repo [tornado-celery](https://github.com/mher/tornado-celery/blob/master/examples/tornado_async.py) by [mher](https://github.com/mher) (creator of celery-flower) from 2018
4. This code example uses asyncio-tornado to handle io-bound http request, and celery to handle the cpu-bound tasks, hopefully echoing the quote:

> It's quite common to use Celery as a distributed layer on top of async I/O frameworks (top tip: routing CPU-bound tasks to a prefork worker means they will not block your event loop).

```py
from tornado import gen
from tornado import ioloop
from tornado.web import asynchronous, RequestHandler, Application

import tasks

import tcelery
tcelery.setup_nonblocking_producer()


class AsyncHandler(RequestHandler):
   @asynchronous
   def get(self):
       tasks.sleep.apply_async(args=[3], callback=self.on_result)

   def on_result(self, response):
       self.write(str(response.result))
       self.finish()


class GenAsyncHandler(RequestHandler):
   @asynchronous
   @gen.coroutine
   def get(self):
       response = yield gen.Task(tasks.sleep.apply_async, args=[3])
       self.write(str(response.result))
       self.finish()
```