# Celery Log file can't be found

Tags: logging, celery

I am trying to see if the log or print commands are working inside my task.

When I run the following command:

> celery -A robobud.celery worker -f -l info

It tells me that my task for start and completed, but I have no idea if it actually ran the code inside is.

Please help me figure out where is this "log" file I keep reading about.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import time
import json
import logging
from channels.layers import get_channel_layer
from robobud.celery import app
from .models import Program



log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

@app.task
async def pump(program_id, amount1, amount2):
    # time sleep represent some long running process
    time.sleep(3)
    # Change task status to completed
    #program = Program.objects.get(pk=program_id)
    log.debug("Running progam_name=%s", program.name, amount1, amount2)

    #program.status = "completed"
    #program.save()
    print("pumping")
    print(program_id, amount1, amount2)

    #Chatroom name
    chat_room = "program" + str(program_id)
    print(chat_room)
    channel_layer = get_channel_layer()

    #Create Dictionary
    taskResponse = {
            "action": "completed",
            "program_id": program.id,
            "program_name": program.name,
            "program_status": program.status,
        }

    # Broadcasts the message to be sent
    await channel_layer.group_send(
        chat_room,
        {
            "type": "task_message",
            "text": json.dumps(taskResponse)
        }
    )

    @database_sync_to_async #Critical when pulling data from data using async
    def set_program_status(self, program_id):
        program = Program.objects.get(id=program_id)
        program.status = "Completed"  # change field
        program.save() # this will update only

    # Send status update back to browser client
    #if program_name is not None:
    #    Channel(reply_channel).send({
    #        "text": json.dumps ({
    #            "action": "completed",
    #            "program_id": program.id,
    #            "program_name": program.name,
    #            "program_status": program.status,
    #        })
    #    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[I'm not sure how well celery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39815771/how-to-combine-celery-with-asyncio) plays with asyncio since celery is multi-processing, while asyncio is about single process, but here is a simple task that will show you how to use logging with celery:

```
    from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger
    from robobud.celery import app


    log = get_task_logger(__name__)

    @app.task
    def logging_task(name):
        log.info('hello %s', name)
```

A quick note, the way you started celery looks wrong.  You can use the following syntax to log to stderr:

```
celery worker -A robobud.celery worker -l info
```

This command, though, only logs those messages that are logged at info or above (i.e., not debug).  If you want to put celery output into a logfile, [you can use the `-f` or `--logfile` switch to specify the location of the file](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#variables-in-file-paths), e.g.:

```
celery -A robobud.celery worker -f /var/log/celery/%h-%I.log -l info
```