# How to call async function inside a celery task

Tags: websocket, celery, django-channels

I have a web chat using websockets (AsyncWebsocketConsumer, django-channels). I'm using celery to parse a request but it halt with no debbugable (for me) errors every time I try to send the response back to the consumer.

This attempt give me the next error:

```
@shared_task
def execute(command, parameter, room_group_name):
    if command == '/stock':
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.run_until_complete(sendData(stock(parameter), "BOT", room_group_name))
        return True
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(sendData("I do not understand that parameter", "BOT", room_group_name))
    return True


from channels.layers import get_channel_layer

async def sendData(message, from_, room_group_name):
    channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
    import datetime
    currentDT = datetime.datetime.now()
    datetime = currentDT.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    await channel_layer.group_send(
        room_group_name,
        {
            'type': 'chat_message',
            'username': from_,
            'datetime': datetime,
            'message': message
        }
    )
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
```

Error:

```
[2019-05-12 18:01:15,491: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-1] Task chat.tasks.execute[8a69afca-8173-46d0-84bc-4ee5ce7782ca] raised unexpected: OSError(9, 'Bad file descriptor')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/juan/Documents/manu/dev/python_challenge/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 385, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/juan/Documents/manu/dev/python_challenge/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 648, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/juan/Documents/manu/dev/python_challenge/chat/tasks.py", line 14, in execute
    loop.run_until_complete(sendData(stock(parameter), "BOT", room_group_name))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 455, in run_until_complete
    self.run_forever()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 422, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1396, in _run_once
    event_list = self._selector.select(timeout)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/selectors.py", line 577, in select
    kev_list = self._kqueue.control(None, max_ev, timeout)
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor, but I cannot find where it is coming from.

celery==4.3.0

Comment: Why call the sendData method in an event loop? That shouldn't be necessary

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to combine Celery with asyncio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39815771/how-to-combine-celery-with-asyncio)