# Celery + Channels: receive message in worker

Tags: celery, django-channels

I'm building a sort of interactive game using django and celery.
Celery task is processing game logic.

Django/channels will be receiving messages from game ui, which need to be passed to same celery task (per game).

I haven't found a way to send messages to active celery task using channels, is there a nice way to do this?

Comment: Active celery task? what do you mean by that? the tasks are run like normal functions. You call them and they execute and exit. Maybe some code and more explanation will make your question clearer

Comment: @Ken4scholars, I mean implementing a two-way communication between client and celery worker (with channels magic in between). All examples I've found describe only communication from worker to client.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE: [Turns out that celery 4 doesn't work well with asyncio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39815771/how-to-combine-celery-with-asyncio), so the solution below keeps raising `got Future <Future pending> attached to a different loop`.**

---

I found a way via creating a channel in celery task:

tasks.py:

```
@app.task
def task(channel_name):
    worker_channel_name = async_to_sync(channel_layer.new_channel)()
    async_to_sync(channel_layer.send)(channel_name, {'type': 'ping_pong', 'message': worker_channel_name})
    r = async_to_sync(channel_layer.receive)(channel)
```

consumers.py:

```
class Consumer(WebsocketConsumer):

    def receive(self, data):
        ...
        tasks.task.delay(self.channel_name)

    def ping_pong(self, event):
        worker_channel_name = event['message']
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.send)(worker_channel_name, ...)
```

Using this, I can make further `receive` calls use acquired `worker_channel_name` to communicate with the worker directly.

A bit which is quite unclear is if I should store `worker_channel_name` on client or inside of `Consumer` (if subsequent websocket requests land on the same node).

Comment: It's not very clear what you want to achieve. If you want to communicate with the cosumer from the celery task, you simply use `channel_layer.send()` giving the channel name. If you want to start a celery task from the consumer, then it's just like running a celery task from any normal python code. Why create a new channel inside the celery task?

Comment: I want to receive further messages into ongoing celery task.