# Deploying Celery Tasks from Asyncio Event Loop

Tags: python, asynchronous, celery, python-asyncio, celery-task

I have a backend application that is currently written with asyncio: fastapi for a web server, sqlalchemy 1.4 + asyncpg for an async database driver. I have a need to deploy tasks to workers that will run and update the host application. Currently I am using `aio_pika`, but would like something more robust such as `celery` with `flower`.

I understand that celery is not integrated with asyncio. I also have read through [answers like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43325237/3124409) and my concern is not having the tasks be async, that is trivial. I am concerned about launching tasks from within the main event loop.

My primary question, does `my_task.delay()`/`my_task.apply_async()` block the running thread **at all**? If so, would a better approach be to use multiprocessing workers that `get` items from a central `mp.Queue`, or a `ProcessPoolExecutor`, and then deploy celery tasks only from that worker process?

I want to deploy tasks and, ideally, be notified when they are complete. This can be done from within the task itself via the `fastapi` interface, though. I just want to ensure that deploying tasks does not block the async event loop.

Comment: There will be some blocking when publishing the task to the broker. You can avoid that using [an executor](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#executing-code-in-thread-or-process-pools) to call `my_task.delay()` or other celery-related functions, as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do something with an answer from the post you linked ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69585025/10209967)).
Basically I took his code and modified a little bit. It seems to work correctly for most cases utilizing simple tasks, but I guess it is not completely safe, it is just a workaround that I made. Here's the code:

```
import asyncio

from celery import Celery


class AsyncCelery(Celery):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.patch_task()

    def patch_task(self):
        TaskBase = self.Task

        class ContextTask(TaskBase):
            abstract = True

            async def _run(self, *args, **kwargs):
                asyncio.set_event_loop(asyncio.get_event_loop())
                result = TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
                return await result

            def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
                loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
                try:
                    return loop.run_until_complete(self._run(*args, **kwargs))
                except:
                    return asyncio.run(self._run(*args, **kwargs))

        self.Task = ContextTask
```