# Why am I not getting results of SQL query back from using encode databases?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, python-asyncio, fastapi

I have the following but for some reason instead of getting results of my query, I am getting something else

Here is the Python package am using

> https://pypi.org/project/databases/

And here is the documentation

> https://www.encode.io/databases/database_queries/

```
from databases import Database
database=Database('postgres://redacted')
await database.connect()
...
...
...
query = "SELECT orders.id AS orders_id, orders.notification_method AS orders_notification_method WHERE shipped=True"
result = await database.fetch_all(query=query))
```

Here is what am getting instead of getting results of my query

> print(result)

```
[<databases.backends.postgres.Record object at 0x7fb3f415ac50>, <databases.backends.postgres.Record object at 0x7fb3f415ae30>, <databases.backends.postgres.Record object at 0x7fb3f415a470>, <databases.backends.postgres.Record object at 0x7fb3f415af50>, <databases.backends.postgres.Record object at 0x7fb3f415ad70>, <databases.backends.postgres.Record object at 0x7fb3f415ab30>, <databases.backends.postgres.Record object at 0x7fb3f415a7d0>, <databases.backends.postgres.Record object at 0x7fb3f415ae90>]
```

And type says it is a list

> print(type(result))

```
<class 'list'>
```

How do I return the actual result of the SQL query which is to return all rows from the query?

#### What I really want to do

> here is `sqlalchemy` version that works but using `databases` package not working as mentioned above

What I pretty much want to achieve is to have similar result from sqlalchemy query like below and be able to iterate over the rows from the result of the query

```
...
...
...
class Orders:
    id: Optional[int]
    notification_method: str
    shipped: Optional[bool]

...
...
...
session = create_session()
result=session.query(Orders).filter(Orders.shipped == True)
```

> print(result)

```
SELECT orders.id AS orders_id, orders.notification_method AS orders_notification_method FROM orders 
WHERE orders.shipped = true
```

> print(type(result))

```
<class 'sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query'>
```

And then I want to be able to iterate over the rows

```
for r in result:
    print(r)
```

> output

```
Orders(id=1, notification_method='call', shipped=True)
Orders(id=2, notification_method='sms', shipped=True)
Orders(id=3, notification_method='call', shipped=True)
```

Just want to get similar result as this sqlalchmey one but using `databases` as mentioned at beginning of this question

Comment: what is "actual result" if not the `Record`? If I check the source code, `Record` encapsulates the values of each row in `.values` property. What is the problem you have with it? Also you probably want to do  [Query](https://www.encode.io/databases/database_queries/#queries) instead of [Raw Query](https://www.encode.io/databases/database_queries/#raw-queries)

Comment: i want it to return result of my query...i mean the code shows what i want..i want to print the result of the sql query

Comment: how do i return the rows from the sql query?

Comment: i updated question with more context...anything am missing?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7784148/understanding-repr-function-in-python

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`databases.backends.postgres.Record` is a subclass of the [`collections.abc.Mapping`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Mapping).

It does contain the result (the "actual result") of the query execution.
In order to "extract" the values, you can do the following:

```
result = await database.fetch_all(query=query))
for rec in result:
    print(tuple(rec.values())  # or you could use `dict(rec.items())` as well
```

---

**Edit-1**: Single result (from comment)

If you execute single query, you should be able to print/convert as per below:

```
rec = await database.fetch_one(query=query)
print(rec)
print(tuple(rec.values()))
print(dict(rec.items()))
```

resulting in something similar to:

```
<databases.backends.postgres.Record object at 0x??????>
(1, 'sms')
{'orders_id': 1, 'orders_notification_method': 'sms'}
```

Comment: what if there is a different query that returns a single row and is fetching a single row? like `result = await database.fetch_one(query=query))` how will i get the single dictionary of the single row result? i tried `dict(rec.items())` and got `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'` how do i return the dictionary of that single row for `fetch_one` query?

Comment: I have updated the answer, but check carefully your code, single query should work as well.

Comment: one other question since you the only one really helpful...celery does not work when i add `async` to the task function...so how do i use the encode databases package with celery? seems databases is only async to query the database with every query ran with `await` and celery does not with `async def function():`...has to be `def function():`...will appreciate your help again..thanks

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not use celery. But most likely this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43325237/99594) will help you.

Comment: for some reason `res.items` is None for me so I can't call it, if you have this too you can use `dict(res._mapping)`. I used to use `dict(res.items())` but now I got error. why so?

Comment: @larick
For future references, maybe is because of this: https://www.encode.io/databases/database_queries/. View last paragraph. (Query result). To keep in line with SQLAlchemy 1.4 changes query result object no longer implements a mapping interface. To access query result as a mapping you should use the _mapping property. That way you can process both SQLAlchemy Rows and databases Records from raw queries with the same function without any instance checks.